# Hangouts notifications appearing above xscreensaver

Tags: google-chrome, arch-linux, notifications, xscreensaver, google-hangouts

When my screen is locked (with XScreenSaver on Arch Linux with Xfce), popup notifications from the Hangouts Chrome extension appear on the screen. Is there any way to prevent this?

This is also occurring with awesome-wm and Chromium.

Comment: Seriously though, which window manager are we talking about here (if any)? There is a good chance that this will be important when giving an answer to this.

Comment: My bad, should've included that. I'm running Xfce, so it's xfwm4.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue with Xfce on Debian. I did not test other desktop environment yet.